# How to fetch the latest Post for specific users using NSPredicate and CloudKit?

Tags: ios, nspredicate, icloud, cloudkit

Let's say I have the following model in iCloud:

```
 ___________         ___________
| Users     |<-_    | Posts     | 
|-----------|   |   |-----------|
| firstName |   |   | text      |
| lastName  |   --- | user      |
 -----------         -----------
```

I need to fetch the latest `Posts` for specific `user` references.

Currently I'm using a predicate like this:

```
let userRefs: [CKReference] = [...]
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K IN %@ AND creationDate >= %@", "user", userRefs, NSDate.twentyFourHoursAgo)

let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Posts", predicate: predicate)
query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
```

But it gives me all user `Posts` for the last 24 hours. Is there any way to get only one, the latest, post for **each** supplied user references?

The desired result would be an array of the latest `Posts` for specific users (e.g. [user1, user2, user3]):

```
[
    Post<text, user1>
    Post<text, user2>
    Post<text, user3>
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to retrieve an other number of records than the default (usually max 100) then use a CKQueryOperation and set the .resultsLimit

In your case you could set it to 1 when executing a query for only 1 user.

The query that you actually want to execute is not possible with CloudKit because you would need some sort of aggregate query. Aggregate queries are not supported. So the only way around this is by executing a query for each user to get it's latest post.

There is however a workaround that could work. I have done something similar before. The moment a user adds a new post, you could also update the user data and add the latest post to the user recrodType. You would have some duplicate data, but you could get all the latest posts by just querying the users.

Comment: Thanks! The workaround seems like a reasonable trade-off.